# Problems using Rangebreaks plotly

Tags: python, graph, time-series, plotly, finance

I was making a time series graph using Plotly however the x-axis has too many labels. I did some research and I think that I could use Rangebreaks to help fix this issue but I'm not sure. I would ideally like there to be fewer x-axis labels. I'll disclose my code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#Initial data & get dataframe 
start = dt.date(2022,3,1)
end = dt.date(2022,3,7)
ticker = 'SPY'
df = yf.download(ticker,start,end,progress=False,interval='1m')
#Make Graph
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df['Adj Close'],
    mode='lines'))
fig.update_layout(xaxis={'type':'category'})
fig.show()
```

Here is what the graph looks like:
[image]

I did actually change the x-axis type on my code but this was done for a reason, to prevent my graph from having large gaps in it like so:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- looking at data,  trading is closed from 4pm to 9:30am
- this can be simply excluded:

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours from 4pm to 9:30am
    ]
)
```

#### full code

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Initial data & get dataframe
start = dt.date(2022, 3, 1)
end = dt.date(2022, 3, 7)
ticker = "SPY"
df = yf.download(ticker, start, end, progress=False, interval="1m")
# Make Graph
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df["Adj Close"], mode="lines"))
# fig.update_layout(xaxis={'type':'category'})
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours from 4pm to 9:30am
    ]
)
```

#### output

[image]

Comment: I think it's not only me, but when using `rangebreaks`, the performance of plotting deteriorates significantly? [ref](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-rangebreaks-make-chart-mega-slow-mega-lag/51911?u=drorata)